# How to export svg area to eps?

Tags: python, svg, inkscape, eps, pycairo

I would like to export (clip/crop) just part of svg. I tried to call command

```
inkscape leave1.svg -E leave2.eps --export-area=0:0:500:500
```

But it seems that it works only for PNG, not for EPS.

Is there any other solution?

I would like to avoid to code a script what will find crossing of svg elements with given area and adjust them according to the border. I would prefer some already done solution.